# T-SQL split string containing alpha and numeric characters by variable delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to split a string that has 3 set Alpha Characters that can appear in any order followed by a numeric value. The issue I am having is that the order of the alpha characters isn't fixed. And neither is the number of numeric values after the alpha character it may contain any of the following examples:

```
X1Y45Z1
Y25Z1
X1Y9Z1
X2Z6
```

With a a lot of help from our local IT ( I am still learning SQL) I have managed to separate out X Y and Z into separate columns with the numbers after them, but they don't always appear in order

- Col1 may contain X or Y
- Col2 may contain Y or Z
- Col3 may contain Z or nothing

I am trying to get a result like the following:

If X is in Col1, Show number(s) after X, in new column "X", if Y is in col1, Show number(s) after Y in new column "Y", etc.

At present we are using 2 cte's to break up the string. and I am trying to simplify it so that I can search the string, have 3 columns after created 'X','Y','Z' and put the correct number(s) after each Alpha delimiter into it. I should note I **Do Not** have full admin access so I cannot create new tables or update/insert data or clean it.

Also apologies if this is slightly formatted incorrectly. It is my first post on StackOverflow

```
declare @tbl table
(
    Col1 varchar(100), <-------This Column contains the values I want
)

insert into @tbl
    select Col1,
    from table1, 
    where xyz

;with cte as
(
    select
        Col1,
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(**Col1**,'P', '</x><x>P'),'C', '</x><x>C'),'I', '</x><x>I'),'M', '</x><x>M'),'S', '</x><x>S'),'Q', '</x><x>Q'),'L', '</x><x>L'),'T', '</x><x>T'),'E', '</x><x>E'),'R', '</x><x>R'),'U', '</x><x>U'),'W', '</x><x>W')
 **Col1NODES**
    from 
        @tbl
)
, cte2 (Col1, Col1Nodes) as
(
    select
        Col1,
        convert(xml,'<z><x>' + Col1nodes + '</x></z>') **Col1NODES**
    from 
        cte
)
select 
    Col1, 
    isnull(Col1Nodes.value('/z[1]/x[2]','varchar(100)'),'-') F1,
    isnull(Col1Nodes.value('/z[1]/x[3]','varchar(100)'),'-') F2,
    isnull(Col1Nodes.value('/z[1]/x[4]','varchar(100)'),'-') F3
from 
    cte2
```

Current output is below:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your intended output in tabular format ?

Comment: You showed your current output.But What is your expected output?

Comment: I am puzzled by >>If X is in Col1, Show number(s) after X, in new column "X",<< Is the result column name "Col1" or "X"?  e.g. X1Y45Z1 -> Col1="X1" and Col2="Y45" and Col3="Z1".  I could go on guessing, but is is much more helpful for YOU to show expected output.  Also, what are the rules for when other alpha chars than X, Y, Z appear? reject the data to some error file? Also, is there a max number of digits that can appear between alphas? reasonably say 5? or 200? What are the string SEARCH criteria?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Pardon donPablo,
Only 3 Alpha characters are relevant , X,Y,Z -There wont be any other letters used.

I would like the column names to be 'X,Y,Z'  - Col1 is how the data is input through a GUI system by our operators. 

Theoretically the number of digits after each character could be between 0-1000. is it unlikely to need more than 4 numeric values after an alpha.

Preferred output format would be as in the answer specified below by Zhorov

I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2016+ you may try to use the following solution, based on JSON. The important part is to transform the input data into a valid JSON object (`X1Y45Z1` is transformed into `{"X":1,"Y":45,"Z":1}` for example). After that you need to parse this object with `OPENJSON()` function using the appropriate `WITH` clause to define the columns in the output.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   TextData nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (TextData)
VALUES
   ('X1Y45Z1'),
   ('Y25Z1'),
   ('X1Y9Z1'),
   ('X2Z6'),
   ('Z1X6')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.TextData, j.*
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(
   CONCAT(
      N'{',
      STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(d.TextData, N'X', N',"X":'), N'Y', N',"Y":'), N'Z', N',"Z":'), 1, 1, N''),
      N'}'
   )   
) WITH (
   X int '$.X',
   Y int '$.Y',
   Z int '$.Z'
) j
```

Output:

```
---------------------
TextData    X   Y   Z
---------------------
X1Y45Z1     1   45  1
Y25Z1           25  1
X1Y9Z1      1   9   1
X2Z6        2       6
Z1X6        6       1
```

For versions before SQL Server 2016, you may use an XML based approach. You need to transform text data into an appropriate XML (`X1Y45Z1` is transformed into `<row><name>X</name><value>1</value></row><row><name>Y</name><value>45</value></row><row><name>Z</name><value>1</value></row>` for example):

```
SELECT
   TextData,
   XmlData.value('(/row[name = "X"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4)') AS X,
   XmlData.value('(/row[name = "Y"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4)') AS Y,
   XmlData.value('(/row[name = "Z"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4)') AS Z
FROM (
   SELECT
      TextData, 
      CONVERT(
         xml, 
      CONCAT(
           STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(d.TextData, N'X', N'</value></row><row><name>X</name><value>'), N'Y', N'</value></row><row><name>Y</name><value>'), N'Z', N'</value></row><row><name>Z</name><value>'), 1, 14, N''),
           N'</value></row>'
         )
      ) AS XmlData
   FROM Data d
) x
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll run through it Monday and see how it goes. If the output is as your example it should be perfect

Comment: @JoshuaTyrrell Updated answer with XML based approach.

Comment: Hi @Zhorov,

Thank you very much for this response it worked perfectly once my DB admin managed to break it down and reverse engineer it. He was then able to provide me a base template which I was able to modify to get the exact output I needed